# Как сделать карточки аватарок как на картинке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.subscribers{
}
.subscribers ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;

}
img{
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-right:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribers">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="subscribers_img">
        <img src="http://preview.ab-themes.com/boat/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/team_member4.jpg">
        <div class="bite"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://mgdvq45m3ss2gaon92odwxol.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/member-9.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://themes.themewaves.com/nuzi/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2013/05/Team-Member-3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.masterslider.com/features/templates/ms/staffcarousel/9.jpg">
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать карточки аватарок как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается создать пустое место  на правой стороне для картинок.

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Не получается создать пустое пространство на правой стороне для картинок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычный бордер

```css
.subscribers {}

.subscribers ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribers">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="subscribers_img">
        <img src="http://preview.ab-themes.com/boat/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/team_member4.jpg">
        <div class="bite"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://mgdvq45m3ss2gaon92odwxol.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/member-9.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://themes.themewaves.com/nuzi/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2013/05/Team-Member-3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.masterslider.com/features/templates/ms/staffcarousel/9.jpg">
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста....